# RDLC: ReportParameter Vs DataSource - Which is better and why?

Tags: c#, ssis, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I want to create a report which will have only one page, say information about only one customer. It should be noted that I'll always have to show information about one customer at one time in a report. That means, there is no scenario where I'll be passing collection of more than one customer.

For now, I've used Data Source and bind it with the report. Though I need to pass collection as a ReportDataSource, that collection will always have one item.

So, is this a correct approach? Shall I use ReportParameter instead of having Data Source? Is there any performance drawback of using DataSource? Is there any performance advantage of using ReportParameter?

Also, using DataSource gives me a liberty of writing a framework which can take inputs as report and collection, and then I can easily generate a report. In case of ReportParameter, I'll need to use reflection to loop through every property and then create ReportParameter.

Please suggest the recommended approach for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A good business practice is to have a parameter where you specify which customer you want to report on. In your data source, you simply include the parameter in your WHERE clause. For SQL Server it would look something like this:

```
WHERE CUSTID = @CustomerParameter
```

Your report is just a template to display the results of that query for the selected customer.

Comment: Thanks Steven for looking into this.

Comment: Do you mean instead of using DataSource, create a ReportParameter and assign it the object of Customer and then bind the report with the ReportParameter? I doubt if we can assign user defined type to ReportParameter. Please give more details if possible. Also, could you please elaborate more on the business practice? Reference links would also help. Sorry, if I'm asking for too much. I just need a strong reason to use ReportParameter instead of DataSource.